# Largest change in the water level

Tags: density

> Which would produce the largest change in the $\ce{H2O}$ level when added to water in a $\pu{25 mL}$ graduated cylinder?
>
> (**A**) $\pu{10.0 g}$ of $\ce{Hg}$ $(d = \pu{13.6 g/mL})$
> (**B**) $\pu{7.42 g}$ of $\ce{Al}$ $(d = \pu{2.70 g/mL})$
> (**C**) $\pu{5.09 g}$ of iron pyrite $(d = \pu{4.9 g/mL})$
> (**D**) $\pu{2.68 g}$ of oak $(d = \pu{0.72 g/mL})$

I approached this question by dividing the mass by density to find the volume change. Thus, I got the answer (**D**), but the answer is (**B**).

Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Because it’s density is less than 1, the oak floats.

Therefore it displaced less than its full volume; some of the floating oak is above water.

Since it’s 2.68g of oak, it displaces only the volume equivalent to 2.58g of water.

Answer (score 0):

Because oak has a density less than water (1g/mL), it won't be fully submerged. For substances more dense than water, they will be fully submerged so you don't have to worry about it. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=151&v=sMkHKMsBEl8&feature=emb_title) to calculate how much of the oak will be submerged.